# Adding vertical whitespace after equation

Tags: vertical-spacing, flalign

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
        &\text{Now}\; u(x,0)=\sin (2\pi x)&&\\
        &\Longrightarrow\; \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
        \sin \left(n\pi x\right)=\sin (2\pi x)\\
        &\Longrightarrow\;a_2=1\; \text{and all others $a_n's$ are zero.}\\
        &\text{Hence the solution is}: u(x,t)= e^{-
            4\pi^2t}\sin \left(2\pi
        x\right)
        \addlinespace[0.5cm]
    \end{flalign*}
\textbf{Problem-3:} Solve: 
\end{document}
```

I want to add some vertical whitespace locally after `end{flalign*}`. So I added `\addlinespace[0.5cm]`. But it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you insert `\bigskip` -- or, if that's too much, `\medskip` or even `\smallskip` -- right before `\textbf{Problem 3.}`.

I would also replace `\def\baselinestretch{2.0}` with

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} 
\setstretch{2.0}`
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{2.0}

\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} 
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\dots % no blank line immediately before '\begin{align*}'
\begin{align*}
        &\text{Now } u(x,0)=\sin (2\pi x)\\
        &\Longrightarrow\; 
         \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\pi x)=\sin(2\pi x)\\
        &\Longrightarrow\;a_2=1 \text{ and all other $a_n$'s are zero.}\\
        &\text{Hence the solution is: $u(x,t)= e^{-4\pi^2t}\sin (2\pi x)$}
\end{align*}
    
\bigskip % <-- or \medskip, \smallskip, or whatever
\noindent
\textbf{Problem 3.} Solve \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a blank line before `\bigskip`?

Comment: @ManjoyDas - The blank line is optional.